# SD read only - how to make USB automount read write

Tags: usb, mount, fstab

I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.pi3g.com/2014/04/make-raspbian-system-read-only/) to make the SD card of my pi read only.
However when I plug in a USB drive stick, which is then auto mounted by the usbmount package as /media/usbX , the usb stick is also read only.

How do I get it to automount as read and write?

I guess it is read-only because it is mounted below /
And / is readonly because /etc/fstab has:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
[...]
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    ro,noatime        0       1
[...]
```

Comment: I would remove usbmount -- is [currently unmaintained](http://usbmount.alioth.debian.org/) and the last release was 2007 -- and look into creating your own udev rule if you want automounting, or just mount it however you want with `mount`.